# Report Automation in Bloomberg

Tags: api, automation, bloomberg

On a daily basis I have to export and save or email reports from Bloomberg. Although this is a simple process, is there a way to automate this process?

I've looked into the Bloomberg API, but haven't seen much relating to reporting automation.

**Example 1:**
Enter a Bloomberg command, Export, Rename the file to today's day, Save in a folder.

**Example 2:**
Enter a Bloomberg command, Enter specific criteria (filters), export to Excel, Save and Send report through email.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using TerminalConnect to automate some of these tasks.